# Getting corrupted cookie value from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets

Browser sends a cookie like `fbm_123456=base_domain=.test.com;` (it's a cookie that was set by Facebook Javascript SDK), it's how I see from FireBug.

But when i'm reading it on server side, my `cookie.getValue()` returns only `base_domain` as value, I mean that `=.test.com` part is lost. All other cookie parameters are null (that's fine).

How it's possible? Maybe I've missed something with cookies, and it's some kind of special cookie? How I can get original cookie value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie is invalid. '=' characters are not permitted in cookie names or values. If you are using Tomcat then in later versions you can use the following system property to allow the invalid cookie to be read:

```
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_EQUALS_IN_VALUE=true
```

The correct cookie value should be:

```
fbm_123456="base_domain=.test.com"
```

(note the quotes)

Comment: Thank you! it's not so good news :( I can't change cookie format (its FB cookie), and don't have access to system properties (it's a plugin, not a final app). Is there any other way to read raw cookie value?